# Retrieve all keys in a hash table into a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, hashtable

The coding language is C#3.0
What is the most optimum method to retrieve all hashtable keys into string separated by a delimiter ","
Is the for loop or the foreach loop the only option?

Update: the keys are already strings

Regards,
naveenj

Comment: Are the keys strings already? i.e. is it a `Dictionary<string, foo>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you really mean a non-generic `Hashtable`? You could use LINQ, assuming that's available to you:

```
string keys = string.Join(",", table.Keys.Cast<object>()
                                         .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                         .ToArray());
```

There may be faster ways, but that's the way I'd go for the sake of readability. Only micro-optimize when you've proved it's a bottleneck.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `IDictionaryEnumerator`:

```cs
string text = "";
IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = table.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
   text += enumerator.Key + ", ";
   text += enumerator.Value + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table.Keys.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```