# Querying Hashtable key LINQ expression C#

Tags: c#, linq, hashtable

I have a hashtable that has key/value pairs as follows,

```
Hashtable h1 = new Hashtable();
h1.Add("@USD_Type","123");

        public class USDParameters
        {
            public const string USDType = "@USD_Type";
            public const string USDId = "@USD_ID";
            public const string USDName = "@USD_Name";
        }
```

Sometimes, I might also have `"@USD_ID"`, `"@USD_Name"` keys in the hashtable.

I would like to query all the keys in the hashtable which start with `@STD_` and match against the names in `USDParameters`. If the name is not found in hashtable then I need to build a string that has the key(minus @) from the hashtable.

For e.g. "The following key(s) missing from the hashtable - USD_ID, USD_Name"

Comment: *query all the keys in the hashtable which start with* - it's not how hashtables work; they're optimized for exact key lookup. You query them by knowing the exact keys and they quickly tell you whether it's there or not

Comment: *If the name is not found in hashtable then I need ... the key from the hashtable* - it doesn't make sense

Comment: Which part of this are you struggling with? Getting a collection of the values found in constants on the class? Finding keys that don't start with a specific value? Creating a comma-separated string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenging part is to query on the keys:

```cs
var keys = h1.Keys.Cast<string>()
  .Where(x => x.StartsWith("@STD_"));
```

Once you have the list in this enumerable type it is much easier to look for missing keys.

Comment: I think it is rude to assume taht OP did not try  to search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20keys%20in%20the%20hashtable%20string - shows plenty of examples of this code already like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404869/retrieve-all-keys-in-a-hash-table-into-a-string.... but that's just me.

Comment: What's even the point of using a hashtable if you're going to search it like it's a list? Seems to me that the keys to look up can be derived and searched exactly. Don't be led by what OPs say to do; they're asking questions because they don't know. Also, hashtable is pretty ancient.. maybe discussing more modern alternatives would be useful

Comment: @CaiusJard Unfortunately, it's an old piece of code, so stuck with HashTable, need to query the keys.

Comment: I still think you're going about it the wrong way. One does not have (as a ridiculous example) a million keys in a hashtable and 3 keys known (std_id, std_type, std_name) and run a loop that looks through a million keys trying to find each one in the list of 3 to know if one or more of the 3 are missing from the table. One just takes the 3 and asks the hash table if they're present. That's 3 lookups, not (upto) 3 million

Comment: All fair points, one thing to consider is Big O complexity. One loop around the hash keys is linear complexity. Start nesting in the algorithm and this becomes quadratic, which can grow to cubic and crush the performance.